# How to convert a mix string of normal English , Russian(Cyrillic) and encoded Russian string into normal string by using java

Tags: java

Lits explain the problem,
I have a pattern of string from a third party API call. I am just giving the example of the string what that API return.
ex -

```
Статья 1 Все люди рождаются свободными и равными в своем достоинстве и правах. Они наделены разумом и совестью и должны поступать в отношении друг друга в духе братства,

Article 1 All people are born free and equal in dignity and rights. They are endowed with reason and conscience and should act towards each other in a spirit of brotherhood,

Ð°Ð½Ð°Ð»Ð¸Ð·Ñ‹ Ð´Ð°Ð²Ð¸Ð´ Ð¼Ð°ÑˆÐ° Ð›Ð•ÐžÐÐ¢Ð¬Ð•Ð’Ð ÐœÐÐ Ð˜Ð¯ Ð•Ð“ÐžÐ ÐžÐ’ÐÐ
_Ñ‚ÐµÑ€Ð°Ð¿ÐµÐ²Ñ‚_Ð›ÐµÐ¾Ð½Ñ‚ÑŒÐµÐ²Ð° Ð’Ð¾Ð´.Ð¿Ñ€Ð°Ð²Ð
```

This above type of mix string(it's just a prototype) I am getting from calling of a third-party API, some part of the string is in Russian and some part is in English and some part is encrypted.
But when I decrypt or convert it into UTF-8 type character it's not working.
The solution of this problem should be like this

```
Статья 1 Все люди рождаются свободными и равными в своем достоинстве и правах. Они наделены разумом и совестью и должны поступать в отношении друг друга в духе братства,

Article 1 All people are born free and equal in dignity and rights. They are endowed with reason and conscience and should act towards each other in a spirit of brotherhood,

анализ давид маа НТЬА А Я  НА
_еапев_еонева од.пав
```

Can we solve it by using JAVA?

Comment: "...some part is encrypted." How?

Comment: @KevinBoone The encrypted technology could be anything, we don't know what type of encryption is used. we just have the encrypted data like Ð°Ð½Ð°Ð»Ð¸Ð·Ñ‹ Ð´Ð°Ð²Ð¸Ð´ Ð¼Ð°ÑˆÐ° Ð›Ð•ÐžÐÐ¢Ð¬Ð•Ð’Ð ÐœÐÐ Ð˜Ð¯ Ð•Ð“ÐžÐ ÐžÐ’ÐÐ
_Ñ‚ÐµÑ€Ð°Ð¿ÐµÐ²Ñ‚_Ð›ÐµÐ¾Ð½Ñ‚ÑŒÐµÐ²Ð° Ð’Ð¾Ð´.Ð¿Ñ€Ð°Ð²Ð

Answer (score -1):

You need to inspect the text character by character, determine if the character is "normal" or an encryption code.

```
StringBuilder output= new StringBuilder();
char[] chars = userText.toCharArray();

for (int index = 0; index < chars.length; index++)
{
    if ( isEncryption( chars[index] ) )
        output.append( decrypt( chars[index] ) );
    else
        output.append( chars[index] );
}

System.out.println(output.toString());
```

If the encryption is multi-character, then it gets a little more complex

```
StringBuilder output= new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder encrypted= new StringBuilder();
boolean isInEncrypt=false;

char[] chars = userText.toCharArray();

for (int index = 0; index < chars.length; index++)
{
    if ( isEncryption( chars[index] ) )
        {
            isInEncrypt=true;
            encrypted.append( chars[index] );
        }
    else
        {
            if ( isInEncrypt )
            {
                output.append( decrypt( encrypted.toString() ) );
                encrypted.setLength(0);
                isInEncrypt=false;
            }
            else
               output.append( chars[index] );
        }
}

if ( isInEncrypt  && encrypted.length() > 0 ) 
  output.append( decrypt( encrypted.toString() ) );
              
System.out.println(output.toString());
```

Comment: This solution is not working, can you please share the isEncryption and decrypt method of your code, Cause in the problem we don't know what type of encryptions is used.

Comment: That is impossible. There are many different ways to encrypt/decrypt information. Unless you know which one is used, you either have to go to the source of the information, or try each one until it works. Of course it might be proprietary to the source, and if they are not wiling to give it up, then there is nothing you can do. You would also need the decryption key if you do get the right method, and again you would have to go to the message source to get that.